# Heavy memory utilization Sails.js app upgraded from node 12 to 14 keeps rebooting in Cloud Foundry

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, cloud-foundry

After upgrading 2 of our Sails application from Node 12 to 14 the application started rebooting or getting stuck in CloudFoundry, there are no visible errors on the logs and the memory spikes to 800Mb (each deployment has 4GB available). When running the applications locally with any node version the issue is not reproducible. Has anyone experience issues with CloudFoundry is there some configuration to allow the application to better manage the available memory?

Attached New Relic data for the failure which happened around 2:15 memory and CPU went all the way down to 0

[image]